# Selecting first item, if initial value does not exist

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-combobox, kendo-ui-mvc

Here we have my combobox:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
    .Name("depots")
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .DataValueField("Value")
    .Height(500)
    .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
    .Events(ev =>
    {
        ev.Change("onDepotsChangeEvent");
        ev.DataBound("onDepotsDataBoundEvent");
        ev.Select("onDepotsSelectEvent");
    })
    .HighlightFirst(true)
    .Suggest(true)
    .Value(SOME INITIAL VALUE)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:550px; max-width:100%;" })
    .DataSource(source => source.Custom()
        .Group(group => group.Add("Group", typeof(string)))
        .Transport(transport => transport
            .Read(read =>
            {
                // Censored ;)
            })
        )
    )
)
```

As you can see, I am setting an initial value with the ".Value(something something". This means that when the combobox loads, the item on the list corresponding to the value, is selected. It works fine as intended.

The problem is when there is not an item with a value corresponding to the initial set value. If that happens, the initial value is shown in the input field of the combobox. After searching around, this is apparently by design and not an error.

What I want to do is, if an item does not exist in the combobox, with the same value as the initial set value, the first item on the list should be selected.

I have searched and searched for days now, with no solution, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

In case it matters, here are the three event methods:

```
function onDepotsSelectEvent(e) {
    if (e.item) {
        var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
        $.post("@Url.Action("SetSelectedDepotSession", "PartialView")", { id: dataItem.Value });
    }
}

function onDepotsChangeEvent(e)
{
    if (this.value() && this.selectedIndex === -1) {
        this._filterSource({
            value: "",
            field: this.options.dataTextField,
            operator: "contains"
        });
        this.select(1);
    }
}

function onDepotsDataBoundEvent(e)
{
    var widget = e.sender;

    if (widget.dataSource.view().length === 0) {
        widget.text("");
        widget.enable(false);
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION**

Here is the databound event code with the fix:

```
function onDepotsDataBoundEvent(e)
{
    var widget = e.sender;

    if (widget.dataSource.view().length === 0) {
        widget.text("");
        widget.enable(false);
    }

    if (widget.select() === -1) {
        widget.select(0);
    }
}
```

What it does is, at first if there is no items at all, the combobox is disabled. Then, if the initial value does not exist on the list, the first item on the list is selected instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is an odd behaviour though. It is like if the widget *adds* the invalid value to its list. I checked that if you do `.val()` directly in the input element or `.value()` in the widget instance, you get the invalid value, but if you do `.select()`, it returns `-1`, as there is no DataItem related to that value. That is a start.

What works for me is to clear the widget's value on `dataBound` event if the `.select()` returns `-1`. Something like:

```
if (this.select() == -1) {
    this.value(null);
}
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ATOzUjep)

Comment: Ah! That did the trick! I was sure that the solution was something minor that I have overlooked. I need to do some more testing, also with different browsers as kendo behaves differently in Edge and Firefox for example (well, at least the version I am using).
I used your piece of code, but added a select, to select the first item on the list. I have updated my OP with the solution.

Comment: @FrederikT nice to hear that! Kendo's development is all about small things and tricks tho haha

Comment: Yeah tell me about it. Really a source of many headaches. For all that they do well, they have an equal amount of spaghetti code and lacking documentation.